# Где в WPF файл App.config?

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.

На данный момент есть у меня приложение под WinForms, переписываю его под WPF.

В файле App.config WinForms содержится следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<runtime>
<legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1"/>
</runtime>
<startup> 
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Каким образом данные настройки (legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1") можно включить\импортировать в проект на WPF?

P.S. Грубо говоря, если я просто импортирую файл App.config в WPF проект, данные настройки из файла будут выполняться?

Comment: @VladD, корректно отловить исключения не получается:  http://hashcode.ru/questions/371472/c-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Пометьте второй коммент как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конфигурация рантайма, по идее, не зависит от используемого UI-фреймворка. Другое дело, что сам фреймворк может использовать потоки по-другому.

А зачем вам политика игнорирования исключений от .NET 1.0? Не лучше ли корректно ловить бросаемые исключения там, где нужно?

---

A app.config там же, он снова-таки от UI-фреймворка не зависит.